# Atypical Regular Expression to search within file

Tags: regex

Let me explain to you at a high level as to what is it that I am trying to do here in C# (language is pretty inrrelevant considering the question that I have).

I have a bunch of files (let us say text files), which contain a lot of data and directory structure links to those more files

For Example:- A file myfile.txt will look like this..

```
This is a text file. This file has very few lines of data like bla bla bla and links like
D:/Presentations/Sales/Demo.pptx
and more links like 
D:/Word_documents/Studies/worddoc.doc
```

What I have to do is to get the list of all these files with the directory structure they are  in. Fortunately, all of them are in D:/ but there can be at max 3 levels of directories to within wherein the file could exist.

I've written all the code and all I am muddled up with is the regex to look for the file pattern. This is Algo that I had in my mind to look for the file:-
1. Search for the file to look for D:/
2. grab the text starting / until a '.' (dot) is encountered (this will constitute the directory structure and the name of the file)
3. then grab the next 3/4 characters (file extension) - there will be different types of MS Office files, I won't worry too much about whether to look for 3 or 4 characters after the .(dot)

Let me summarize as to what I am stuck with - regex search pattern to look for ///filename.extension

and then I need to get the filename to see if the file exists and then go through its contents.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With a little backtracking this should do:

```
^D:/.*/(.*)
```

You should use it with the multiline option.

For example:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("^D:/.*/(.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var str = @"This is a text file. This file has very few lines of data like bla bla bla and links like
D:/Presentations/Sales/Demo.pptx
and more links like 
D:/Word_documents/Studies/worddoc.doc";

var matches = rx.Matches(str);
var names = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand as much as posible your needs.

Here is a regular expression that will find any Windows or UNC (with file name including extension with 3 or 4 characters as you requested) path match

`(?:\b[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$]+\\[a-z0-9_.$]+)\\(?:[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*\.[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]{3,4}`

Hope this helps.